# Draw path between points within certain radius using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a scatter plot that has paths between all points within a certain distance of each other using ggplot2, similar to the attached image below. How could I modify the following code to include paths between all points within a distance of 0.2 to each other?

```
    library(ggplot)
    ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) +
        geom_point()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this duplicates line segment draws which is not very efficient but I think that's what you're looking for

```
df_iris <- data.frame(x = iris$Sepal.Length, y = iris$Sepal.Width)
df_graph = data.frame(x1 = rep(df_iris$x,nrow(df)),
            y1 = rep(df_iris$y,nrow(df)),
            x2 = rep(df_iris$x,1,each=nrow(df)),
            y2 = rep(df_iris$y,1,each=nrow(df))
            )
df_graph$dist = sqrt((df_graph$x2-df_graph$x1)^2+(df_graph$y2-df_graph$y1)^2)
 
threshold = 0.2
df_graph = df_graph[df_graph$dist>0&df_graph$dist<threshold,]

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df_graph)+
  geom_segment(aes(x=x1,y=y1,xend=x2,yend=y2),color="blue")+
  geom_point(data=df_iris, aes(x=x,y=y),size=0.2)
```

[image]